# Why is my uvmap created using uvproject modifier scaled up?

Tags: uv, modifiers

I am trying to use uvproject modifier to copy uvmap to arrayed object from other object. For whatever reason the resulting uvmap is scaled up, like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQYGc.jpg
Why doesn't it line up perfectly?

Here the file: https://www118.zippyshare.com/v/phZYwOET/file.html

Comment: a scale issue? Try to apply scale (ctrl+A, then scale)

Comment: All scales are 1.

Comment: Go in the curve's settings and uncheck "Radius"

Comment: That doesn't do anything?

Comment: Anybody else have any ideas? I have never used this modifier before so I could be missing some obvious setting.

Comment: How do I even adjust the scale? The scale values do nothing... Is there a modifier that can scale an uvmap? I really don't want to collapse my modifier stack.

Comment: Can't edit my previous post. So I think the modifier is broken it seems. At least I can use uvwarp modifier to scale it but naturally that makes it impossible to line up with the other uvmap. Oh well

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the reason you have this problem is that:

1. The original object named **Plane** in the outliner has been scaled up by 5 from its original size.
2. The UV's of this Plane needs to be rotated by 90°.

The quickest way to fix this is to work with the **Empty**

1. Select the Empty.
2. Scale it up by a factor of 5. ( <kbd>S</kbd>  <kbd>5</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> )
3. Rotate along Z axis 90°. ( <kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> <kbd>90°</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> )

The result of doing this should be as in the screen shot below:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean scaled up by 5? All the scales are 1? Why do the scales need to be 5x? Why does the object need to be rotated by 90 degrees? Does the modifier always need to be scaled by 5 and then rotated 90 degrees? I mean the issue was not that I did not know how to fiddle with it to get it to eventually match but I want to try to understand why it needed fiddling at all? All the scales are 1, all rotations match, why doesn't it line up straight away like one should expect it to?

Comment: First of all thanks 3fingeredfrog. However, I am not going to accept this as an answer because it doesn't answer my question. Why doesn't the uvproject modifier line up with the target mesh and why does it need to be rotated and scaled seemingly randomly to get it to line up? I did not ask for how to line it up but why doesn't it line up.